# What is best approach to provide a WMS of world coverage of 1 meter CIB?

Tags: tiles

I have been tasked with creating WMS's of several raster types to include 1 meter CIB. We have an overall ESRI environment to include ArcGIS Server and we have a butt load of original CIB data (world coverage). Not asking for the perfect answer, unless you want to provide it, but could sure use some pointers, general directions and maybe some sage advice of what NOT to do.

Comment: I hope you have many terra-bytes of storage for your tile cache. And time to generate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to creating a TMS like OpenStreetMap, Google Maps, etc ?

I was working some time ago on a similar project, but only for USA data, and we decide to preprocess the data and create a tile pyramid images structre to serve it much more faster and with less computer resources.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is some useful advice on this [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/u/walkermatt/p/building-a-national-tile-server) from Matt Walker where the hardware/software combination is discussed on building a national tile server for the UK.

[image]